# Remove horizontal space between proof and start of the proof

Tags: amsthm

I am trying to prove some theorem by using proof environment, but somehow the result is different when I use article as my document class and aip-cp document class.

The result when I use article as document class is
[image]

The result when I use aip-cp as document class is
[image]

Is there a way to use aip-cp document class but when I use proof environment it does not add some horizontal space between the proof and the first text of the proof?

Here is the code

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}[letter]

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\iint\relax
\let\iiint\relax
\let\iiiint\relax
\let\idotsint\relax
\let\openbox\relax
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{lemma}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
Sample text
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
We begin to proof the equation by using the definition of A
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Note:
I somehow can reduce the space by using `\hspace{-6mm}` but it does not look natural.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you please make  a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Sorry it is my first time here. I have already edited my post. Is that what it means by MWE?

Answer (score 1):

The space between "Proof." and the text is controlled by `\labelsep` You can change this length to your needs:

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}[letter]

\let\iint\relax
\let\iiint\relax
\let\iiiint\relax
\let\idotsint\relax
\let\openbox\relax

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{
\setlength\labelsep{6pt}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
We begin to proof the equation by using the definition of A
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `aip-cp` class sets a very large value of `\labelsep`. However, changing the value of this parameter inside the `proof` environment is not a good solution, because it might make inner lists different from the outer ones.

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\iint\relax
\let\iiint\relax
\let\iiiint\relax
\let\idotsint\relax
\let\openbox\relax
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\proof}
 {\item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape#1\@addpunct{.}]}
 {\item[]\textit{#1\@addpunct{.}}\ }
 {}{}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{lemma}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
Sample text
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
We begin to proof the equation by using the definition of A
\begin{itemize}
\item abc
\end{itemize}
and the proof is done.
\end{proof}

\begin{itemize}
\item abc
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]